# How to patch a function to return a nested dictionary

Tags: python, mocking

I am trying to patch a function to return a nested dictionary like so:

```
with patch('boto3.client') as mock:
        mock.create_platform_endpoint.return_value = {'EndpointArn': 'another_arn'}
        mock.get_endpoint_attributes.return_value = {'Attributes': {'Enabled': 'true', 'Token': 'new_token'}}
        device.register_with_aws()
```

This fails, as when accessing the dictionary, the code just finds MogicMock functions e.g. `<MagicMock name='client().create_platform_endpoint().__getitem__()' id='4619515160'>` or `<MagicMock name='client().get_endpoint_attributes().__getitem__().__getitem__()()' id='4424507800'>`

I guess I could mock these `__getitem__()` calls, but is there a more elegant solution than pretending to be a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `create_platform_endpoint` and `get_endpoint_attributes` are methods of the class `boto3.client`, this might work for you:

```
with patch(boto3.client, 'create_platform_endpoint', return_value={'EndpointArn': 'another_arn'}):
    with patch(boto3.client, 'get_endpoint_attributes', return_value={'Attributes': {'Enabled': 'true', 'Token': 'new_token'}}):
        device.register_with_aws()
```

Assuming that `create_platform_endpoint` and `get_endpoint_attributes` are attributes of the method `boto3.client`, this might work for you:

```
with patch('boto3.client.create_platform_endpoint', return_value={'EndpointArn': 'another_arn'}):
    with patch('boto3.client.get_endpoint_attributes', return_value={'Attributes': {'Enabled': 'true', 'Token': 'new_token'}}):
        device.register_with_aws()
```

Check out the documentation for `patch` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).

Few other pointers:
If you have something like this in your class:

```
class Foo(object):
    ...
    def bar(self):
        ...
        value = boto3.client()    # Assume you are using the method boto3.client() here
        ...
        return whatever           # Assume that this is a dictionary you want
```

And now if you want the dictionary returned from `Foo().bar()` to be patched with some other return value, then this can help you:

```
with patch.object(Foo, 'bar', return_value={}):
    foo()
```

If you want to mock the value `Foo().bar().value`, then try to mock the client method itself

```
with patch('boto3.client', return_value={}):    # This makes the value `value` as {}.
    foo()
```

Comment: this gives me `AttributeError: <function client at 0x107833378> does not have the attribute 'create_platform_endpoint'` Are you sure that nested mocking works this way?

Comment: I assumed that `boto3.client` was a class. If it was a method then try the edited post.

Comment: Edited the post. Checkout and let me know.

Comment: BTW, you also need to check the order of `create_platform_endpoint` and `get_endpoint_attributes` how they are called. The nested patch also should be in the same way. Well it might not matter, but just a pointer.

Comment: I still get the same error. I think the function `boto3.client` returns an object which in turn has functions. So the error message makes sense. The function does not have an attribute or function called `create_platform_endpoint`

Comment: Yeah, then you need to figure out from which `class` or `method` does `create_platform_endpoint` is being called and patch it accordingly. If it is a method just use the `patch()` method and if it is a class then you can use `patch.object()` as shown in the documentation.

Comment: One more thing - always remember that you need to patch the `class` or `method` from which your patch target is being called. Don't try to mock it from another method where it is being used, you might get different behavior.

Comment: Yeah. Because, you are using that `boto3.whatever` method in your class. You can patch that to get the desired return value.

Comment: Updated the post with relevant examples to avoid the confusion

Comment: Thanks. The problem in my case is that the functions I want to mock are added dynamically to the object. So I can't patch them this way. Which is why I hoped to do it from a lower level...